# adding tags to text inside a tag

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I have the following html document that is auto generated by a third party :

```
<body>
<pre>
<b>Field1</b> something 
<b>Field2</b> something else
...
</pre>
</body>
```

I want to eventually highlight the text that comes after the text that is bolded under certain circumstances, so I opted to use greasemonkey for that.
Since that text doesn't have any id associated with it, I was thinking of recreating the page and between`</b>` and `<b>` I will surround all the text with a mark tag with the ID being the text of the field before it, like so:

```
<body>
<pre>
<b>Field1</b> <mark id=Field1>something </mark>
<b>Field2</b> <mark id=Field2>something else </mark>
...
</pre>
</body>
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this without having to recreate the page? e.g inserting elements after each of the  tags?

Comment: I think recreating the page is the best option. Using something else is always a gamble since it will never completely fit your desires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plain JS, you can select all the `b` nodes, loop over it, and in each iteration, replace the sibling text node with new `mark` node.

Check the working example below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('b').forEach(b => {
  let textNode = b.nextSibling;
  let newNode = document.createElement('mark');
  newNode.id = b.innerText;
  newNode.innerHTML = textNode.textContent;
  textNode.replaceWith(newNode);
})
```

```html
<pre>
<b>Field1</b> something 
<b>Field2</b> something else
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other bold elements on that particular page, and assuming you're using a text editor, you could do a "Replace" (Ctrl + h in Sublime Text and VS) do a search for , in the replace section put back the closing tag and add the additional edit "<"Element, DIV, Class, ID etc>", and click replace all.

Comment: It would require to download the page separately and apply it constantly. I want it to appear instantly when I open the page on a browser.